# I own a rooted Moto E with very little usable internal memory. But it does have a MicroSD slot. Can I change its default storage?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, sd-card

I own a rooted Moto E.

It has about 2GB of usable internal memory.  It frequently runs out of memory.

Luckily, it also has a MicroSD card slot.

Can I change its default storage?

Comment: Have you tried `adb shell pm set-install-location 2` using ADB ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! 1.  I have edited your question so that other people will be more likely to understand it. But the last sentence ("Can I change its default storage?") is unclear.  Please [edit] and clarify, so that you might get more upvotes. 2. Also, what ROM are you running, and what version of the ROM?